# <input type="search"> and jQuery Autocomplete

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, search, autocomplete

Once i change the `type` of the `<input>` element to the html5 type `search`, jQuery's Autocomplete functionality just won't work anymore.

I use jQuery Mobile, and i am trying to use the ["search" input type](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0/docs/forms/search/) with [jQuery UI Autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/)

Answer (score 1):

It's because the  `jQuery UI Autocomplete` select only elements with `type="text"`

Have you tried to attach the Autocomplete to the elements with `id` selector?

Comment: Yes. I call the autocomplete like this: `$("#address").autocomplete({"source":fetch_address,"select":select_address});`

Comment: @Dimdum.וואלה אחי, אין לי מושג

Answer (score 0):

Using:

```
<input type="text" data-type="search" />
```

will give the same visual results as

```
<input type="search" />
```

But the *autoComplete* plugin will still work, also broken with `type="search"`,
https://github.com/commadelimited/autoComplete.js

Might also fix jQuery UI Autocomplete?