# How can I change input type of Yii CJuiAutoComplete?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, yii, autocomplete

I'm new to Yii and I've been able to use `CJuiAutoComplete` for autocomplete.

I have two questions:

1. By default, the input box is of type `text`. How can I change the type to `search`?
2. By default it uses jQuery UI CSS styling. How can I drop that and use my own styling?

   ```
   $this->widget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiAutoComplete', array(
       'model' => $myModel,
       'attribute' => 'name',
       'source' => Yii::app()->createUrl('search/autocomplete'),
       'options' => array(
           'minLength' => '2',
           'showAnim' => 'fold',
           'select' => 'js: function(event, ui) {
               this.value = ui.item.value;
               $("#item_id").val(ui.item.id);
               return false;
           }',
       ),
       'htmlOptions' => array(
           'maxlength' => 50,
           'type' => 'search' // <- This didn't work
       ),
   ));
   ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2) For this you can specify the css file using the `cssFile` attribute this defaults to "jquery-ui.css" you can change to your own file; see this documentation for more details 
see http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CJuiWidget#cssFile-detail

Comment: 1) You are wrong. It's no problem using `type="search"`. See fiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/TJc8z/1/. I want to use `search` since I'm doing HTML5.

2) Ah, thanks :)

Comment: well for 1) http://stackoverflow.com/a/9173119/1900483; perhaps it jui version makes a diff?

Comment: No. Firstly they are using jQuery Mobile. Secondly the post is 2 years old.  So that's not a problem any more. But the question is how I can change the input type which Yii creates :)

Comment: Search telephone, and number fields are supported only from yii 1.1.14 what version are using ? see http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHtml#activeSearchField-detail